# How to set a 'has many :through' a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have defined my models as follows. I am trying to do `@user.orders` using `has_many`. I have defined a method:`orders` to show the behaviour I want.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locationable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :orders, ->(location) { where(location.locationable_type == 'User') }, class_name: 'Order', foreign_key: :drop_location_id
  # but this does not check for type
  # it produces the SQL: SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."drop_location_id" = $1
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # location is polymorphic, so type of location can be merchant/user
  belongs_to :pickup_location, class_name: 'Location'
  belongs_to :drop_location, class_name: 'Location'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, as: :locationable

  # TODO: make it a has_many :orders instead
  def orders
    Order.where(drop_location: locations)
  end
end
```

Using a method doesn't feel like the *rails way*. Moreover, I want it to work well with `rails_admin`.

Comment: I think you're right that using a method there is not the Rails way. But also scoping in a has_many statement is something I've never seen done, nor tried to do. I recommend: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for best practice design for Active Records Associations in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now, you should have received an error indicating that you can't use has_many through a polymorphic association.  If you think about it, it makes perfect sense, how could your ORM (ActiveRecord) formulate the query as the joins would be horrendous.

Comment: 'horrendous' maybe but it is deterministic. I just need an additional check for `type` (along with the usual `id`). Like it happens in my `orders` method: `SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."drop_location_id" IN (SELECT "locations"."id" FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."locationable_id" = $1 AND "locations"."locationable_type" = $2)`